# What should an idiomatic `Display` implementation write?

Tags: rust

The trait documentation says

> Display is similar to Debug, but Display is for user-facing output, and so cannot be derived.

But what does that mean? Should it write the full string-encoded value even if that results in a 500 character output? Should it make a nice and friendly representation suitable for display in a user interface even if that results in `to_string()` not actually returning the full value as a string?

Let me illustrate:

Say I have a type that represents important data in my application. This data has a canonical string-encoding with a very specific format.

```rust
pub struct BusinessObject {
    pub name: String,
    pub reference: u32,
}
```

First, I want to implement `Display` so I can use it for making easily readable log messages:

```rust
impl Display for BusinessObject {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        // Formats like `Shampoglak (7384)`
        write!(f, "{} ({})", self.name, self.reference)
    }
}
```

Now, let's implement a method that returns the canonical standard string format for `BusinessObject` instances. As the `as_str()` method name is idiomatically only used when returning a string slice and that is not possible in this case, one could think that the most straightforward approach would be to implement a method `to_string()` for this.

```rust
impl BusinessObject {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        // Formats like `Shampoglak00007384`
        format!("{}{:0>8}", self.name, self.reference)
    }
}
```

But no! This method name is already implemented as part of the automatic `ToString` trait implementation that we have because we implemented `Display`.

What does an idiomatic implementation of `Display` write? A full representation of a value as a string or a friendly, human-readable representation of it? How should I structure my code and name my methods if I need to implement both of those? I am specifically looking for a solution that can be applied generically and not just in this specific situation. I don't want to have to look up what the behavior of `to_string()` for a given struct is before I use it.

I didn't find anything in the documentation of associated traits and various Rust books and resources I looked into.

Answer (score 1):

> What does an idiomatic implementation of Display write? A full representation of a value as a string or a friendly, human-readable representation of it?

The latter: `Display` should produce a friendly, human-readable representation.

> How should I structure my code and name my methods if I need to implement both of those?

"Full representations" of values as strings would more correctly be known as a string *serialisation* of the value.  A method `fn into_serialised_string(self) -> String` would be one approach, but perhaps you want to consider a serialisation library like [serde](https://serde.rs) that separates the process of serialising (and deserialising) from the serialised format?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I agree that implementing `Serialize` and `Deserialize` seem like the right approach to serialisation. My issue with using `Display` like that is that it automatically adds a a `to_string()` method. Who would expect that method name to return a human-readable version? It's easy to get bugs this way.   

I have received a second reply on this question that backs the alternative so I'm not sure what to take away from this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

> What does an idiomatic implementation of `Display` write?

It writes *the obvious string form of that data*. What exactly that will be depends on the data, and it may not exist for some types.

Such a string representation is not necessarily “human friendly”. For example, [the `Display` implementation of `serde_json::Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html#impl-Display-for-Value) (a type which represents arbitrary JSON data structures) produces the JSON text corresponding to the value, by default without any whitespace for readability — because *that's the conventional string representation*.

`Display` should be implemented for types where you can say there is “**the** string representation of the data” — where there is one obvious choice. In my opinion, it should *not* be implemented for types where there isn't one obvious choice — instead, the API should omit it, in order to guide users of the type to *think about* which representation they want, rather than giving them a potentially bad default.

> A full representation of a value as a string or a friendly, human-readable representation of it?

In my opinion, a `Display` implementation which truncates the data is incorrect. `Display` is for *the string form of the data,* not *a name or snippet of the data.*

> How should I structure my code and name my methods if I need to implement both of those?

For convenient use in format strings, you can write one or more methods which return wrapper types that implements `Display` (like [`Path::display()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display) in `std`).

Comment: Thank you for your considerate reply! I like the ideas of omitting the implementation if there is a chance of ambiguity and also implementing the wrapper type!